# API data is showing in the browser's console but not on the webpage - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api-design

I am new to API design and I am trying to implement an API call that simply displays data from an API server I found online using the vue.js project via CLI. Though I am able to see the results in the console of the browser, I am not able to see the actual data display on the webpage I am working on.  I have seen similar questions like mine, but none of those seem to have the same issues I am, using Vue. After spending a few days researching, I just can't seem to find the issue and I am pretty sure it is a pretty fundamental thing I am messing up, which makes it even more frustrating to admit defeat on this.  Here is the code in question:

```
<template>
  <div class="health">
    <p>{{response}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "HelloHealth",
  data() {
    return {
      response: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url:
        "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/random",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "5788793819msh9c9b16c2298d826p1e5fefjsn3d5bde507db6",
        accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Here are the results I get in my console for the code:

[image: API console results.]

Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you does not set any `response` data yet, in your `response` data property. Instead of call `API` directly in `mounted()`, you can call this `API` in methods from `mounted()`. This is good coding. Exactly, how it is works:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      response: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getResponseData() {
      axios({
        method: "GET",
        url:
          "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/random",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
          "x-rapidapi-host": "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "5788793819msh9c9b16c2298d826p1e5fefjsn3d5bde507db6",
          accept: "application/json"
        }
      })
        .then(response => {
          this.response = response.data;
          console.log(this.response); //get response data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getResponseData();
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Sukanta!  This worked for me and I have a greater understanding now on how APIs work.  This was a huge help for me and I truly appreciate you answering the question so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting `this.response` to anything other than `""`.
In your `mounted()` call, after the Axios call succeeds, you need to set the response:

```
 .then(response => {
     this.response = response.data;
 })
```

Vue's docs have a pretty nice guide on consuming APIs and integrating data into Vue here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: Thank you LMulvey.  I certainly still have a lot to learn about how APIs are implemented.  This link should serve as a good foundation for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(response => {
      this.response = response.data;
      console.log(this.response); //get response data
    })
```

The response which is returned by axios has different scope.
It's available in only then function.
You should set response of the component as the response returned by axios.